# Issue with title in JPanel Titled Border in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am working with Swing in Netbeans, using the GUI Designer. I have created a JPanel on a JFrame. When I create the border for the JPanel, I select Titled Border, and I put in a name and font.

The problem is that when I see the result, the title is cut, and I can't see it well.

Here are some images.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

[Window http://es.tinypic.com/r/o92zau/9](http://es.tinypic.com/r/o92zau/9)

[image: Border Properties]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What do you mean by "cut"? The titled border "Name" does not seem cut, instead it looks "smudgy" and is hard to read. Is that the problem?

Comment: Have you tried a different font other than "Adobe Arabic 12 Bold"?

Comment: Yes, is for the font, thanks!